# Getting Invalid SQL syntax when using SCN and table alias

Tags: sql, oracle, flashback

I am trying to fetch XMLType data as a String using commit SCN value as

```
SELECT ab.userdata.getStringVal() userdata from MINER.MINERT2 ab  as of
scn(1558393) where ab.ID = 14;
```

But I am getting SQL syntax error. When I use a normal query, without table alias say

```
select col from tablename as of scn(1234) where id=1
```

I do not get any syntax errors.

Comment: Exactly what error you are receiving?

Comment: @Arulkumar sql syntax not properly ended

Comment: Exactly this error `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` ? If so remove the semi-colon in the last, and try again.

Comment: @Arulkumar Yes exactly this error.

Comment: @Arulkumar Nope. Not working

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake. table alias must be written after `as of SCN()`.

So the query

```
SELECT ab.userdata.getStringVal() userdata from MINER.MINERT2 ab  as of
scn(1558393) where ab.ID = 14;
```

must be corrected to

```
SELECT ab.userdata.getStringVal() userdata from MINER.MINERT2  as of
scn(1558393) ab where ab.ID = 14;
```